# Activate ignition effect from hand?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I have 2 questions, one generally-scoped and one specific:

1. Can I activate the effect of Disenchanter while it is still in my hand?
2. In general, can one activate monsters' [ignition effects](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Ignition_Effect) from the hand?

## Disenchanter:

> Once per turn: You can target 1 face-up Spell Card on the field; remove 1 Spell Counter from anywhere on the field, and if you do, return that target to the hand.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, no. It is common knowledge that a monster has to be on the field or revealed from the hand/graveyard/banished zone (if the card permits it) to be able to resolve ANY effect, given the conditions (if any) are met, unless the card says otherwise.

You can always play Disenchanter on the field,  THEN activate its effect.

Comment: Could you please add the exact wording from the rulebook? I would upvote this, but I want to make sure that your answer is accurate and the best way to do that would be to quote the relevant text straight out of the rulebook instead of "the Rulebook specifically says..."

Comment: @Thunderforge , I would, though I have lost the rulebook. I can only remember it. =)

Comment: Well, the rule book [is online](http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/rulebook/). Perhaps you can find the rule there?

Comment: @Thunderforge, I didn't mean that sort if Rulebook; I meant one of those quick start guides

Comment: to my understanding unless the card states that it can be played from the hand then it cant, pretty sure if you asked a konami judge they wouldnt allow this to be done from the hand

Answer (score -2):

1. No
2. Not unless it explicitly says so.

See this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Yugioh101/comments/3z2ei8/question_can_one_activate_monsters_ignition/) for more details.

Comment: Can you add more info in your answer about what the link contains, it is encouraged that a questions and answers has more content.